# Fixing case object identity / pattern matching under serialization

Tags: scala, serialization, equals, case-class

I have a class which gets serialized and deserialized in a session, and I need to perform pattern matching on inner classes. I am having problems with the identity of the inner classes:

```
class Tree(val id: Int) {
  override def hashCode = id
  override def equals(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[Tree] &&
    that.asInstanceOf[Tree].id == id

  case object EmptyValue
}

val t1 = new Tree(33)
val t2 = new Tree(33)

t1 == t2 // ok 
t1.EmptyValue == t2.EmptyValue // wrong -- reports 'false'
```

What is an elegant way to fix the identity for `EmptyValue` to not 'escape path dependency' so to speak. I have code like the following which breaks when serialization is taking place:

```
def insert(point: Point, leaf: Leaf): Unit = {
  val qidx = hyperCube.indexOf(point)
  child(qidx) match {
    case EmptyValue => ...
    ...
  }
}
```

That is, although the compiler says my match *is exhaustive*, I get a runtime `MatchError` when using serialization (I am having custom code that writes to/reads from byte arrays). For example, I am calling from within the tree having `Tree$EmptyValue$@4636` and retrieve a `Tree$EmptyValue$@3601` and they don't match.

**EDIT**

I have conducted further tests, because I would really like to avoid having to move the inner types out, as they will need to have type parameters and thus break all pattern matching code. It looks as if the problem only occurs with that particular `case object`:

```
class Tree {
  sealed trait LeftChild
  case object  EmptyValue   extends LeftChild
  sealed trait LeftNonEmpty extends LeftChild
  final case class LeftChildBranch() extends LeftNonEmpty

  def testMatch1(l: LeftChild) = l match {
    case EmptyValue        => "empty"
    case LeftChildBranch() => "non-empty"
  }

  def testMatch2(l: LeftChild) = l match {
    case EmptyValue      => "empty"
    case n: LeftNonEmpty => "non-empty"
  }
}

val t1 = new Tree
val t2 = new Tree

t1.testMatch1(t2.LeftChildBranch().asInstanceOf[t1.LeftChild])       // works!!!
t1.testMatch2(t2.LeftChildBranch().asInstanceOf[t1.LeftChild])       // works!!!
t1.testMatch1(t2.EmptyValue.asInstanceOf       [t1.EmptyValue.type]) // fails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existential type could express this.

```
scala> case class Tree(id: Int) {
     |    case object EmptyValue {
     |       override def hashCode = 0
     |       override def equals(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[x.EmptyValue.type forSome { val x: Tree }]
     |    }
     | }
defined class Tree

scala> val t1 = Tree(33)
t1: Tree = Tree(33)

scala> val t2 = Tree(33)
t2: Tree = Tree(33)

scala> t1.EmptyValue == t2.EmptyValue
res0: Boolean = true
```

Bytecode for `equals`:

```
scala> :javap -v Tree.EmptyValue

...
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=2
   0:   aload_1
   1:   instanceof  #23; //class Tree$EmptyValue$
   4:   ireturn
...
```

Comment: That's great Eugene. Do you know if this definition of `equals` poses some kind of runtime penality (reflection other than `isInstanceOf`)?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer, showing the resulting byte code, and thus answering my comment question -- it seems this is a really 'cheap' operation :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can try adding a companion object for Tree and defining EmptyValue in it:

```
class Tree( val id: Int ) { /******/ }
object Tree {
  case object EmptyValue
}
```

Comment: The problem is, Tree is actually parametrised in three types, thus `Tree[S, D, A]`. I can only use pattern matching when using inner types, because otherwise the crappy matcher complains about the type erasure. It is a quite complex data structure, moving the inner types out will cost me a day of work. I have edited the question to show that this strangely is only a problem of `case objects` as it seems.